# Highlighting table rows and changing text color

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, highlight

I would like to highlight my rows in table by changing background color and text color. Changing background color works fine, but text color not. What is wrong in my code, that text color does not change onClick?

script.js

```
var preEl ;
var BColor;
var TColor;

function highlight(el){             // funkcia pre zvyraznenie riadkov
  if(typeof(preEl)!='undefined') {
     preEl.text=TColor;
     preEl.bgColor=BColor;
  } 
  TColor = el.text;
  el.text = '#FF0000';  
  BColor = el.bgColor;
  el.bgColor = '#FF3333';  

  preEl = el;
}
```

table

```
<table>
<tr  onClick="highlight(this);" >
        <td>Ferrari F138</td>
        <td>1 000€</td>
        <td>1 200€</td>
        <td>Model monopostu stajne Scuderia Ferrari pre sezónu 2013</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>F138</td>
        <td>Klik pre detaily</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var preEl ;
var BColor;
var TColor;

function highlight(el){             // funkcia pre zvyraznenie riadkov
   if(typeof(preEl)!='undefined') {
     preEl.style.color = TColor;
     preEl.style.backgroundColor = BColor;
   } 
   TColor = el.style.color;
   el.style.color = '#FF0000';  
   BColor = el.style.backgroundColor;
   el.style.backgroundColor = '#FF3333';  

   preEl = el;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
el.text
```

should be

```
el.style.color
```

But I would suggest toggling the class name instead. it would make the code much clearer:

```
function highlight(el) { // funkcia pre zvyraznenie riadkov
    el.className = el.className === 'selected' ? '' : 'selected'
}
```

CSS:

```
.selected {
    background-color: #FF3333;
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z22NU/

#### UPD

To allow only one row to be selected at a time:

```
function highlight(e) {
    if (selected[0]) selected[0].className = '';
    e.target.parentNode.className = 'selected';
}

var table = document.getElementById('table'),
    selected = table.getElementsByClassName('selected');
table.onclick = highlight;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z22NU/1/

Comment: thx it works, but I need only one row highlighted at same time :/

Comment: sorry, it works on jsfiddle, but when I copy it to my files it doesnt work. I'm using Xampp. :(

Comment: What error do you see in console? Make sure variable selected is accessible in the highlight function. Try to move `selected` declaration inside of it.

Comment: table is null: selected = table.getElementsByClassName('selected'); and after click on row, selected is udefined: if (selected[0]) selected[0].className = '';

Comment: You should give table an id, in my example I set `id="table"`, change your HTML accordingly.

Comment: yes, I already do that and I also changes script.js like this http://jsfiddle.net/tfPTB/ ... now I'm getting error: table is null on table.onclick = highlight;

Comment: doesn't work :( still error: table is null - table.onclick = highlight;

Answer (score 1):

Try something else. Use css and [event delegation](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/30/event-delegation-in-javascript/).

Create a class in css:

```
tr.highlighted {
 background: #FF3333;
 color: #FFF000; /* #FF0000 is almost the background color */ 
}
```

In your js-file create a listener function:

```
function highlight(e){
      e = e || event;
      var from = findrow(e.target || e.srcElement)
         ,highlighted = from ? /highlighted/i.test(from.className) : false;
      if (from) 
        from.className = !highlighted ? 'highlighted' : '';
}
// findrow: find parent tr tag of the clicked Element
function findrow(el){
      if (/tr/i.test(el.tagName))
        return el;
      var elx;
      while (elx = el.parentNode) {
        if (/tr/i.test(elx.tagName)) {
            return elx;
        }
      }
      return null;
}
```

And finally assign a click handler to the table element:

```
document.querySelector('table').onclick = highlight;
```

See this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/z6yQ3/)